# firedac and udl as connection string

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, firedac

In TAdocCnnection its easy to set up connection with udl.

just set connection string to

> filename=everything.udl

Is it possible to achieve the same simplicity with FireDac TFDConnection or any other component that uses FireDac?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Defining_Connection_%28FireDAC%29

Comment: is there a class that transform a udl to FireDac ini format?